# delete from table based on other database mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL databases that have the same structure. However, the content is different: DB1 receives the most recent data on the last 10 days every day. DB2 contains data about the last years.

I want to accomplish the following:

Step 1:
Delete from db2.t1 if column1 exists in column1 in db1.t1

Step 2:
Insert all from db1.t1 into db2.t1

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Step 1: Delete from db2.t1 if column1 exists in column1 in db1.t1
>
> Step 2: Insert all from db1.t1 into db2.t1

It looks like you are trying to **merge** data from `db1.t1` into `db2.t1`. If so, then one solution would be to use a mysql `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. This lets you deal with duplicates when executing an `INSERT` query : in your use case, it seems like you can to update every columns from the source table.

First this to work, unless `column1` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, you need a `UNIQUE` constraint on `column1` on the target table (in your use case, you would better add it to the source table too) :

```
ALTER TABLE db2.t1 ADD CONSTRAINT t1_bk UNIQUE (column1);
```

Then :

```
INSERT INTO db2.t1 t_target
SELECT t_source.* FROM db1.t1 t_source
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    t_target.column2 = t_source.column2,
    t_target.column3 = t_source.column3,
    ...
;
```